# Error while setting up Bing API on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to set up the Bing Spell Check API on my Microsoft Azure account. The deployment, however, fails with the following error message:

```
OPERATION ID         492286237BA7FFEB
TRACKING ID          779d79cf-4b12-487f-ba97-c896bbdccb87
STATUS               Conflict
PROVISIONING STATE   Failed
TIMESTAMP            24/2/2017 09.55.58
DURATION             1 minute 22 seconds
TYPE                 Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts
RESOURCE ID          /subscriptions/c68eec07-13e6-4f40-831c-c42f996fca89/resourceGroups/webis2/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/webis
STATUSMESSAGE        {
                         "error": {
                         "code": "RequestConflict",
                         "message": "Cannot replace resource with id 'webis'
                                     because the resource entity tag has changed
                                     while processing this request. 
                                     Please retry the request with the updated
                                     resource."
                         }
                     }
RESOURCE             webis
```

The STATUSMESSAGE suggests to simply retry the request, but this fails, too, with the same error message.

Otherwise, I'm not sure how to resolve the issue, since I obviously have no access to the provisioning process of the Bing Spell Check API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are investigating this.  For now you should be able to work around the issue by deploying to an existing Resource Group instead of creating a new Resource Group during the API account creation.

Update: This issue has been resolved and new API account creation should work correctly.